# Interacting with metamask from Javascript. Etherum is not defined

Tags: metamask, javascript

Im trying to implement a very basic Metamask integration to show balances.
Im working with GoDaddy's website builder which allows you to inject arbitrary html into the  of the page.

This is the code im injecting.

```
<button class="enableEthereumButton">Enable Ethereum</button>
<h2>Account: <span class="showAccount"></span></h2>

<script>
  const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
  const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');

  ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getAccount();
  });

  async function getAccount() {
    const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    const account = accounts[0];
    showAccount.innerHTML = account;
  }
</script>
```

The error i get is "ethereum is not defined"

I have tested this code in the console of Chrome and it successfully launches Metamask. Metamask also works fine with other sites.

Is there something that prevents the  tag from being able to see the ethereum object injected globally by metamask?

Answer (score 1):

You should initialise a web3 object using the Ethereum provider. The following lines should help debug your problem:

To check if MetaMask injected a provider (javascript):

```
const provider = window.ethereum

if (provider) {
 // initialize your app
} else {
  console.log('Please install MetaMask!');
}
```

To check if the provider was injected by MetaMask (javascript):

```
const provider = window.ethereum
if (provider?.isMetaMask) console.log("Using MetaMask!");
```

You can use the MetaMask node package to detect a provider, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metamask/detect-provider (javascript):

```
// This function detects most providers injected at window.ethereum
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';

const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();

if (provider) {
  // From now on, this should always be true:
  // provider === window.ethereum
  startApp(provider); // initialize your app
} else {
  console.log('Please install MetaMask!');
}
```

Once you have discovered your provider you can initialise a web3 object and retrieve the accounts with the following:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
const provider = window.ethereum // or MetaMask's package
const web3 = Web3(provider)
try {
    await provider.enable();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
const account = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0];
```

Hope this helps! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the first part is for testing out with various browsers. I was having a same problem but on chrome itself. I imported web3 package and then added the following code. To which it started working. (However you have to use "web3." functions from now on

```
async loadBlockchainData()
{
    var Web3 = require('web3')
    var web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545')
```

If in case you want to use ethereum only..

```
 async loadWeb3()
{
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) 
    {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) 
    {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else 
    {
        console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
}
```

Use the modern dapp browser part of code (you can experiment with the others as well)

Comment: Im trying to use ethereum only. 
The problem is the window.ethereum or ethereum is not defined when my button press calls the code in my <script> tag